# document.title change delay in Chrome/Edge

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, microsoft-edge

I'm working on a web app (no UI libraries) where I want switching windows to update the document title. By "windows" I mean floating `<article>` elements on the page, not browser windows.

In Firefox 90, the following code runs instantly. It does in Safari 12 also, so I can't call this a WebKit problem. But in Chrome 91 and Edge 91, at least on the macOS 10.14 machine I'm using, there is a noticeable split-second delay between pressing the button and the title changing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onClick="document.title='foo';">foo</button>
        <button onClick="document.title='bar';">bar</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to alleviate this? Trigger some kind of document.title "repaint" or "reflow", if you will?

Comment: I agree with ErrorGamer2000's answer. It might be issue with chromium on macOS and you can provide the feedback about this issue in [chromium project website](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list).

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that this can be fixed, I have noticed the same thing. I think it is created by the programming of the browser itself, not the website.